# Telethon: how to change picture in chat?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, telegram-api

I want to update logo picture in my chat

```
await client(EditPhotoRequest(channel='channel name',
                        photo=input_chat_uploaded_photo))
```

This code works only to channel. Does anyone knows how to do it with chats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the API reference on [editChatPhoto](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/edit_chat_photo.html)

For chats you must pass peers as integer id.

```
await client(EditChatPhoto(chat_id,
           input_chat_uploaded_photo))
```